# How can I get a 'File Name' ONLY from the (File Name + Extension) using substring in C#?

Tags: c#, substring

It seems a simple one but I confused to get it.

Here is the case:

I have a complete file name like `abdcd.pdf` or `efghijf.jpg` or `jklmn.jpeg`,

Now I have to get only the **file name** as `abdcd` or `efghijf` or `jklmn`

Comment: find the last index of the '.', and take the substring from the beginning to that index

Comment: Seriously, why would you bother posting a question here when [Googling  the title](https://www.google.nl/search?q=How+can+I+get+a+%27File+Name%27+ONLY+from+the+(File+Name+%2B+Extension)+using+substring+in+C%23) will get the answer as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        String f = "file.jpg";
        int lastIndex = f.LastIndexOf('.');
        Console.WriteLine(f.Substring(0, lastIndex));
```

Or, like the others suggested, you can also use

```
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
```

Comment: looking up the last '.' will fail if the filename doesn't have a '.'. Following that the call `Substring(0,-1)` will throw an exception. GetFileNameWithoutExtension is th much better option.

Comment: yes you're right, it was assumed that the extension was always present I think ;)

Answer (score 8):

Use Path class static method

```
result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.Substring()`, but I recommend `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` for this task:

```
// returns "test"
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("test.txt")
```

[Go to the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This method is essentially implemented like this:

```
  int index = path.LastIndexOf('.');
  return index == -1 ? path : path.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the API call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileNameWithoutExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileNameWithoutExtension('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use Path static method: [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a method for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There's actually an app for that!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method like this:

```
result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The string returned by GetFileName, minus the last period (.) and all characters following it.